# Error 1004 setting cell value

Tags: vba, excel

When running the following code, I get the error "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". It breaks on the marked line

```
 Dim cwb As Workbook
 Dim csh As Worksheet
 Set cwb = Workbooks.Open("M:\Secretary Resources\AppTracking\SentSurveys.xlsx")
 Set csh = cwb.Sheets("Sheet1")
 ''It breaks on this next line
 csh.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "MM-DD-YYYY HH.MM AM/PM")
 csh.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Value = Survey_Count
```

I've looked at all of the error 1004 answers, and they either did not work (such as unprotecting the sheet), or they did not make enough sense for me to implement.

I simply want to open an existing spreadsheet and add a new row of values to the end of it (without making any changes to the active workbook or active worksheet, which are currently in use by something else). Anyone have any idea as to what I can do to get this to work?

EDIT: This is being performed in a sub and it is not working there.

Comment: works for me, without issue.

Comment: you are going to the bottom of the worksheet and then setting a value in the row below that. ... accessing non-existent cell

Comment: @jsotola Wouldn't that be out of range error? I believe he's getting a different issue here

Comment: the  worksheet is either blank or has value in A1 only   .... do this in the `immediate window` .. `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select` this will probably select the last row cell, and then do `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select`

Comment: @jsotola There is only a value in A1 and A2 right now. I need it to select the row just below it.

Comment: @jsotola So I added a single row of values under A1 and it worked. Why doesn't it work without that?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to jsotola for the answer.

The solution was to fill in the row underneath row 1 with something. I just used '-' marks.

End(xlDown) moves to the last non-empty cell in the column, however, if it already starts at the last non-empty cell in the column, it will skip over as many empty cells as it finds until it either finds more non-empty cells or hits the end of the sheet.

Starting at A1, there was nothing after that, therefore, instead of staying where it started (what I assumed it would do), it instead jumped to the bottom of the sheet. I was then offsetting to a non-existent cell outside of the sheet, thereby giving me the error.